# How would I use a while loop to keep requesting user input

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop

I've tried a couple of things with the while loop and can't seem to get it to work. I want to keep requesting user input until the user inputs the number 0, here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Task10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = input.nextInt();

        if ((year % 4 == 0) || ((year % 400 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
        else
            System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your leap year logic is wrong.

Comment: Although not really what you asked, I see that you posted after the release of JDK 8 which included the introduction of the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) and therefore you can use [static] method [isLeap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#isLeap-long-) (of class `java.time.Year`) rather than do the calculation yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a while loop above input line as:

```
 while(true)
```

And, use `if` condition to `break`.

```
if(year == 0)
    break;
```

Also, condition for `leap year` is wrong in your code. It should be:

```
if((year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
    //its a leap year
else
    //its not
```

PS: As in comments, I'll give a complete code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Task10 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year");
    while(true){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = input.nextInt();
        if(year == 0)
            break;
        if((year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
        else
            System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, worked a charm. Still getting used to while loops and this explanation sunk in!

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something to keep you input loop running until a stopping condition is encountered (which in your case is that when the user inputs `0`)

```
// First get the scanner object with the input stream
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

// Just using do-while here for no reason, you can use a simple while(true) as well
do{
    int input = sc.nextInt();  // read the next input
    if (int == 0) { // check if we need to exit out
        // break only if 0 is entered, this means we don't want to run the loop anymore
        break;
    } else {
        // otherwise, do something with the input
    }
} while(true); // and keep repeating
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your input taking code inside a while loop aned execute while loop untill year is 0 or lesser.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year = 1;
        while(year > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            year = input.nextInt();
            if ((year % 4 == 0) || ((year % 400 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
                System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
            else
                System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why would you make scope of `year` variable local of `main`, when it is never required outside the `while` loop ?!

Comment: @vish4071 it reduces the number of lines of code needs to be written instead of marking the while as true at first and then checking for condition  if year is 0 to break the loop I felt I can make the beginner understand better this way

Comment: It is bad practice. You should try and declare / define variables to use only when they are required. Make it `rule of the thumb`. A few LoC has no effect on project, but, scope of variables and memory etc makes a lot of difference.

Comment: But since it is a small program,  it does not matter much :)

Answer (score -1):

### Simple and best

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

while(sc.hasNextInt()){
int year = input.nextInt();

```
    if ((year % 4 == 0) || ((year % 400 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0)))
        System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
    else
        System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
```

}

---

Until you enter a valid input , the loop will contionue

Comment: The single line of code, in your answer, is not [formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and does not compile. I assume that `sc` is an instance of `java.util.Scanner`. If that instance was created like so: `new Scanner(System.in)`, then `sc.hasNext()` will **never** return _false_, so how does that answer the original question?

Comment: Update for more redable, instance sc created only once, when you enter invalid input loop will be break

Comment: Still haven't learned how to format code using [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)? By the way, the code in your answer still doesn't [compile](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/NxQ).