# Factorial Calculator

Tags: java, loops, factorial

How can I make the program to perform a new or repeat the operation or ask the user to input again a number and know the factorial of it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num, num2 = 1, x, i;

        System.out.println("-------------Factorial Calculator-------------");
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        num = input.nextInt();

        if (num > 0) {
            System.out.print(num + "! = ");
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                if(i < num){
                    System.out.print(i + " x ");
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                }
                if(i == num){
                    System.out.print(i);
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                    System.out.println("\nThe factorial of " + num + " is " + num2);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }else if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please input a valid integer. Program stopped.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I use a while loop to keep requesting user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036087/how-would-i-use-a-while-loop-to-keep-requesting-user-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code that computes the factorial in a separate method and call it from within a loop in main().

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {

    public static void printFactorial(int num) {
        int i = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        if (num > 0) {
            System.out.print(num + "! = ");
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                if(i < num){
                    System.out.print(i + " x ");
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                }
                if(i == num){
                    System.out.print(i);
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                    System.out.println("\nThe factorial of " + num + " is " + num2);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }else if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please input a valid integer. Program stopped.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println("-------------Factorial Calculator-------------");
        while ( true ) {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            printFactorial(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. it says it should be on a private static.

Comment: It should work just fine. The method does not need to be declared private static. I tested it on my system and I know it works. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: sorry for that. Yes it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {
    static boolean readInput = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(readInput) calculateFactorial();
    }
}

private static void calculateFactorial() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num, num2 = 1, x, i;

    System.out.println("-------------Factorial Calculator-------------");
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    num = input.nextInt();
    if(num <= 0) {
        readInput = false;
        return;
    }

    if (num > 0) {
        System.out.print(num + "! = ");
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            if(i < num){
                System.out.print(i + " x ");
                num2 = num2 * i;
            }
            if(i == num){
                System.out.print(i);
                num2 = num2 * i;
                System.out.println("\nThe factorial of " + num + " is " + num2);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }else if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please input a valid integer. Program stopped.");
    }
}
```

Comment: is it not possible without making it a private static? I am actually not yet familiar with the private static.

Comment: If you want to have call `calculateFactorial` from `main` method, it has to be static because non static methods cannot be called from static methods without using objects of the class type, and I updated my answer to calculate factorial only when user input is valid

Comment: @FrancisPutnam have you tried this soln?

Comment: Well, its a bit more advance that what I know right now. So I don't how should I explain it. But thank you for the effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: @FrancisPutnam you can appreciate by upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

use while loop when user not typing a positif number :

```
System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
num = input.nextInt();
while(num<0) {
    System.out.println("Please input a valid integer. Program stopped.");
    num = input.nextInt();
}
```

**code :**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num, num2 = 1, x, i;

        System.out.println("-------------Factorial Calculator-------------");
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        while (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please input a valid integer. Program stopped.");
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (num > 0) {
            System.out.print(num + "! = ");
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                if (i < num) {
                    System.out.print(i + " x ");
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                }
                if (i == num) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                    System.out.println("\nThe factorial of " + num + " is " + num2);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. I tried putting the if statement inside the while loop, it works but theres a problem with the output on the equation or the factorial.

Comment: Also what I would like to happen is to perform another operation after one is complete.

Comment: i fixed the code. and if you want to perform more operations you can use the while loop in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    boolean runMore = true;
    
    while(runMore){
    
    

    int num, num2 = 1, x, i;

    System.out.println("-------------Factorial Calculator-------------");
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    num = input.nextInt();

    if (num > 0) {
        System.out.print(num + "! = ");
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            if(i < num){
                System.out.print(i + " x ");
                num2 = num2 * i;
            }
            if(i == num){
                System.out.print(i);
                num2 = num2 * i;
                System.out.println("\nThe factorial of " + num + " is " + num2);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }else if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please input a valid integer. Program stopped.");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Want to contine : Enter '1' for yes and '0' for no");
    int wantToContinue = input.nextInt();
    
    if(wantToContinue==0){
        
        runMore = false;
    }
    
    }
}
}
```

Comment: code link - https://onlinegdb.com/eyArB-7V7

Comment: it's a bit complicated. What I want to happen is to just like after one number gets the factorial, it would repeat or ask the user again right away to input another number to know the factorial without asking them to input a yes or no to perform another operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactorialCalculator1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int num;
        
        System.out.println("<------Factorial Calculator------>");
        while ( true ) {
            
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        
        boolean runMore = true;
        
        int i;
        int num2 = 1;
        
        if (num > 0) {
            System.out.print(num + "! = ");
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                if(i < num){
                    System.out.print(i + " x ");
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                }
                if(i == num){
                    System.out.print(i);
                    num2 = num2 * i;
                    System.out.println("\nThe factorial of " + num + " is: " + num2);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }else if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Program stopped!");
            System.exit(0);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to figure out this one?                                                                                                                                <------Factorial Calculator------>
Enter a positive integer: 2
2! = 1 x 2
The factorial of 2 is: 2
Enter a positive integer: 3
3! = 1 x 2 x 3
The factorial of 3 is: 6
Enter a positive integer: 4
4! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4
The factorial of 4 is: 24
Enter a positive integer: 5
5! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5
The factorial of 5 is: 120
Enter a positive integer: 6
6! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 6
The factorial of 6 is: 720